Short-circuit in noexcept expressions
given the follow code:
// g++ main.cpp -std=c++23

#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename P>
concept pointer_like = is_pointer_v<P> || requires (P p) { p.operator ->(); };

template<pointer_like P>
constexpr auto func(P p)
    noexcept(is_pointer_v<P> || noexcept(p.operator ->())) // error: 'int *' doesn't have 'operator ->'
{
    if constexpr (is_pointer_v<P>)
        return p;
    else
        return p.operator ->();
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    auto pi = func(&i); // error from here
}

https://godbolt.org/z/Gqq3W4o4h
It seems short-circuit is not performed in the noexcept expression:
noexcept(is_pointer_v<P> || noexcept(p.operator ->()))

My expectation is:

If P is a pointer, is_pointer_v<P> is true so operator -> is not checked;
Otherwise, check if operator -> is valid.

Is it something C++ standard is missing?

Note that only the evaluation order of operands for || is fixed. Both the operands to || must still be valid expressions.

Each sub-expression in the noexcept must be valid individually/separately.
You can use requires to achieve the desired effect/result as shown below:
template<pointer_like P> constexpr auto func(P p)
    noexcept(requires { requires is_pointer_v<P> || noexcept(p.operator ->()); })
{
    if constexpr (is_pointer_v<P>)
        return p;
    else
        return p.operator ->();
}

Working demo

I don't think it works because the requires means the content in {...} is valid but NOT necessary TRUE. Please see the test code: https://godbolt.org/z/ea7Wja6M5.

@DoZerg You're using the old link demo. It works when you use the new link demo. Note the use of requires requires to make this work which is missing in your given demo.

Just noticed! Thanks for the answer!

@DoZerg You're welcome :) Btw your posted answer is actually the same as my answer. You're explicitly using on extra parenthesis which are not needed here but can be used.

The expression in the noexcept needs to be well-formed. The short-circuiting of logical operators only applies to the evaluation of the operands, not to their well-formedness.
The problem can be resolved with another level of indirection that correctly handles the ill-formed operands:
template<pointer_like P>
consteval auto noexcept_check() 
{
    if constexpr (is_pointer_v<P>)
        return true;
    else
        return noexcept(P{}.operator ->());
}

and then the declaration of func is simply:
template<pointer_like P>
constexpr auto func(P p)
    noexcept(noexcept_check<P>()) 

demo

Thanks for the reply! It's the 'standard' way I saw a lot in the STL, though I wonder if there is a shorter approach.

@DoZerg By shorter, do you mean without writing a separate function? You could use the technique with requires as shown in the other answer. Personally, I prefer the named function, since it's easier to read and conveys intent more clearly (both of which are definitely subjective, of course), and it can be reused.
